# How can i add a custom delegate method to my singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, singleton

I am developing a digital magazine reader app and it requires to download magazines first.
While downloading them i want to pass download progress data between viewcontrollers.
That's why i am using singleton design pattern.
I also use NSNotification to update progressBar percentage while its downloading. But i do not think it is quite efficient to send notificiation in every milisecond. So i decided to use delegate design pattern but i don't know to implement a custom delagete method. Any help on custom delegate? And is it the best way to use delegate?

```
// Header

@interface ZXCSingleton : NSObject

+ (id)sharedInstance;

- (BOOL)isDownloadingProduct:(NSString *)productID;
- (void)addToDownloadListWithProductID:(NSString *)productID;
- (void)removeFromDownloadListWithProductID:(NSString *)productID;
- (NSArray *)getDownloadList;

- (void)setDownloadProgress:(float)progress
              withProductID:(NSString *)productID;
- (float)getDownloadProgressWithProductID:(NSString *)productID;

@end

// M

#import "ZXCSingleton.h"

@implementation ZXCSingleton{
    NSMutableArray *downloadList;
    NSMutableDictionary *downloadProgress;
}

+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    static ZXCSingleton *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[ZXCSingleton alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        downloadList        = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        downloadProgress    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)isDownloadingProduct:(NSString *)productID
{
    for (int i = 0; i < downloadList.count; i++) {
        if ([[downloadList objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:productID]) return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (void)addToDownloadListWithProductID:(NSString *)productID
{
    [downloadList addObject:productID];
}

- (void)removeFromDownloadListWithProductID:(NSString *)productID
{
    [downloadList removeObject:productID];
}

- (NSArray *)getDownloadList
{
    return downloadList;
}

- (void)setDownloadProgress:(float)progress
              withProductID:(NSString *)productID
{
    if (progress != [[downloadProgress objectForKey:productID] floatValue]) [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"downloading" object:nil];
    [downloadProgress setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", progress] forKey:productID];
}

- (float)getDownloadProgressWithProductID:(NSString *)productID
{
    return [[downloadProgress objectForKey:productID] floatValue];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a delegate by creating a protocol first for defining the interface required by the delegate :

```
@protocol ZXCSingletonProtocol 

   - (void)downloadProgessUpdates:(float)progress;

@end
```

Create a property for the delegate in your singleton :

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ZXCSingletonProtocol> delegate;
```

Let your view controller conform to that protocol :

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <ZXCSingletonProtocol>
```

and implement the `downloadProgessUpdates` in the view controller as required (e.g. update the UI element with the given progress number). REMEMBER to set the delegate when you initialize the view controller (`viewDidLoad` will do):

```
[ZXCSingleton sharedInstance].delegate = self; // self is the view controller instance
```

In your singleton update the `setDownloadProgress` method to update the delegate as well :

```
[_delegate downloadProgessUpdates:progress];
```